# Build Variants - Android

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
    }
}
```

Need a clarification about the above code.

1. Did the only purpose to rename generated .apk file?
2. Why do I need to add this line `//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck`  ?
3. Would the above line be cause for run-time crash or any issue ?
4. What else can I do with `applicationVariants.all {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

1 Yes, only rename

2 Not sure. outputFile is read-only - this code shouldn't work on newest Gradle

3 No, Gradle doesn't affect to runtime

4 Every Gradle action

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is not working in Android studio 3.2.1.

If want to rename the APK and want to extract proguard mapping file.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('ddMMMyy_HH_mm')
        variant.outputs.all { output ->

            def formattedName  = "${"SampleName" + variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.concat("_")}" +
                    "${variant.buildType.name[0].toUpperCase().concat("_v")}${variant.versionName.concat("_" + formattedDate)}"

            outputFileName = new File("${"v"+variant.versionName.concat("/")}" +formattedName+".apk")

            if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
                copy {
                    from variant.mappingFile
                    into output.outputFile.parent
                    rename { String fileName ->
                        formattedName +  "_mapping.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code will give the apk with ***/BuildVariant/vVersionName/ SampleName_BuildVariant_BuildType_vVersionName_DDMMMYY_HH_mm.apk*** and mapping file.

> You can also set do all above thing only on release build